# Reduction of Order - Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the following initial value problem:

$y'' -y'\tan(t)+2y  =0$

$y(0) = 1$, $y'(0) = \sqrt[]{3}$

I've attempted this problem a couple of times and keep coming up with an incorrect answer. Anyone able help out?

Comment: Use Variation of paramters

Comment: What is $u'$? I guess you mean $y'$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Are you taking a a differential equations course now?

Answer (score 0):

$y''-y'\tan(t)+2y=0$

$y''-\dfrac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}y'+2y=0$

$\cos(t)y''-\sin(t)y'+2\cos(t)y=0$

Note that it has trivial particular solution $y=\sin(t)$ .

Let $y=\sin(t)u$ ,

Then $y'=\sin(t)u'+\cos(t)u$

$y''=\sin(t)u''+\cos(t)u'+\cos(t)u'-\sin(t)u=\sin(t)u''+2\cos(t)u'-\sin(t)u$

$\therefore\cos(t)(\sin(t)u''+2\cos(t)u'-\sin(t)u)-\sin(t)(\sin(t)u'+\cos(t)u)+2\cos(t)\sin(t)u=0$

$\sin(t)\cos(t)u''+2\cos^2(t)u'-\sin(t)\cos(t)u-\sin^2(t)u'-\sin(t)\cos(t)u+2\sin(t)\cos(t)u=0$

$\sin(t)\cos(t)u''+(2\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t))u'=0$

$\sin(t)\cos(t)u''=(\sin^2(t)-2\cos^2(t))u'$

$\dfrac{u''}{u'}=\tan(t)-2\cot(t)$

$\ln u'=-2\ln\sin(t)-\ln\cos(t)+c$

$u'=\dfrac{C_1}{\sin^2(t)\cos(t)}$

$u=C_1(\tanh^{-1}\sin(t)-\csc(t))+C_2$

$\therefore y=C_1(\sin(t)\tanh^{-1}\sin(t)-1)+C_2\sin(t)$

$y(0)=1$ :

$C_1=-1$

$\therefore y=1-\sin(t)\tanh^{-1}\sin(t)+C_2\sin(t)$

$y'=C_2\cos(t)-\tan(t)-\cos(t)\tanh^{-1}\sin(t)$

$y'(0)=\sqrt3$ :

$C_2=\sqrt3$

$\therefore y=1-\sin(t)\tanh^{-1}\sin(t)+\sqrt3\sin(t)$